# I can't extract the ad status from the Meta Ads API to my dataframe

Tags: python, facebook

I already have a script where I am extracting data from the Facebook Ads API to build reports, etc. But I would like to include in my dataframe the status of each ad, to know if it is active or inactive. But I did not find any parameter in the Meta documentation that would answer me that. Can anyone help me?

Currently my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebook_business.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebook_business.adobjects.ad import Ad
from facebook_business.adobjects.insightsresult import InsightsResult
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

# API FACEBOOK:
access_token = '[TOKEN]'
app_secret = '[APP SECRET]'
app_id = '[ID DO APP]'
id_conta = '[ID ACCOUNT]'

FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
    'date_start',
    'date_stop',
    'account_name', 
    'account_id', 
    'campaign_name', 
    'campaign_id', 
    'adset_name', 
    'adset_id',
    'ad_name', 
    'ad_id', 
    'objective',   
    'reach', 
    'frequency',
    'impressions',            
    'spend', 
    'inline_link_clicks',
]

params = {
    'level': 'ad',
    'fields': fields,
    'access_token': access_token,
    'time_range' : {'since' : '2023-08-09', 'until' : '2023-08-09'},
    'time_increment': '1'
}

account = AdAccount(id_conta)
insights = account.get_insights(fields=fields, params=params)
data = []

for insight in insights:
    data.append(insight.export_all_data())
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I already tried to include the field `status` or `effective_status` in the `fields` list, but none of that worked.